# Plotly: How to change the colorscale limits for ternary plots?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm creating ternary plots in Plotly using the `create_ternary_contour()` method described here https://plotly.com/python/ternary-contour/. I want to change the limits of the colorscale.

When I try changing the `cmin` and `cmax` parameters this way,

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis={"cmin": -10, "cmax": 10})
```

there is no change in the resulting figure. Anyone know how I can change the colorbar scale with the `create_ternary_contour()` method?

Comment: Are you looking at the example used to generate the ternary contour titled `'Mixing enthalpy of ternary alloy'`? And also, when you say you want to change the limits of the colorscale, do you want to want to change the underlying data or just the label of the axes?

Comment: Yes, I'm plotting a series of ternary plots like in that example and I'd like to set the colorscale limits on each ternary plot to be the same, so the colors across plots can be compared.

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming to do does not seem to be possible in this case. At least not in a very straight-forward way. But if your main goal is to compare data within shared boundaries you could always rescale your different series using

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
minmax_scale(array)
```

And it seems that all your would have to rescale here is `Al` and `Cu` for your different datasets:

```
Al = np.array([0. , 0. , 0., 0., 1./3, 1./3, 1./3, 2./3, 2./3, 1.])
Al = minmax_scale(Al)

Cu = np.array([0., 1./3, 2./3, 1., 0., 1./3, 2./3, 0., 1./3, 0.])
Cu = minmax_scale(Cu)
```

Or you could just rescale `enthalpy` like so:

```
enthalpy = minmax_scale(enthalpy)
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

Al = np.array([0. , 0. , 0., 0., 1./3, 1./3, 1./3, 2./3, 2./3, 1.])
#Al = minmax_scale(Al)

Cu = np.array([0., 1./3, 2./3, 1., 0., 1./3, 2./3, 0., 1./3, 0.])
#Cu = minmax_scale(Cu)

Y = 1 - Al - Cu
# synthetic data for mixing enthalpy
# See https://pycalphad.org/docs/latest/examples/TernaryExamples.html
enthalpy = (Al - 0.01) * Cu * (Al - 0.52) * (Cu - 0.48) * (Y - 1)**2

# rescale enthalpy
enthalpy = minmax_scale(enthalpy)

fig = ff.create_ternary_contour(np.array([Al, Y, Cu]), enthalpy,
                                pole_labels=['Al', 'Y', 'Cu'],
                                #ncontours=20,
                                #colorscale='Viridis',
                                interp_mode='cartesian')

fig.show()
```

Comment: In this example I would want to scale `enthalpy` though. Not the in-plane axes (Al, Cu, Y) but the out-of-plane z axis

Comment: @EricM OK! I made an edit that shows how to do that instead

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this doesn't actually do what I want. This will scale the z axis of each plot from 0 to 1. But I'd like to keep the original data scale the same, and just set the colorbar scale. Its a plotly issue not a data issue.